# Javascript: Create dictionary from array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, set

I have an array of strings that I get from an endpoint and I need to convert it to key-value pairs for the frontend to display them correctly. I have tried different concepts such as reduce and map but have not been able to get it working successfully. I assume it might be one-liner for someone familiar with FE but has taken forever for a BE person like me.

Here is what I have tried:

```
var input = ['quiz1', 'quiz2'];
const mapping = input.map(x => {"id":x, "label":x};);
console.log(mapping);
```

I am expecting an output of the format

```
[{"id":"quiz1", "label":"quiz1"}, {"id":"quiz2", "label":"quiz2"}]
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Need to wrap object in `()` when you are implicitly returning object. And also remove the inner `;`  .`const mapping = input.map(x => ({"id":x, "label":x}));`

Comment: thanks, that is what I was missing :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply two syntax errors:

```js
var input = ['quiz1', 'quiz2'];
const mapping = input.map(x => ({"id":x, "label":x}));
console.log(mapping);
```

1. Firstly, no semicolon in a un-braced arrow function body.

   This is invalid: `(() => 3;)`. This is valid: `(() => 3)`.
2. Secondly, wrap return obj in `()`.

   This is invalid: `() => {x: 3}`. This is valid: `() => ({x: 3})`.